# If $V$ is a $KG$-Module whose only endomorphisms are scalar multiples of $\operatorname{id}_V$, then $V$ is irreducible

Tags: representation-theory

Let $K$ be a field, $G$ a finite group and $V$ a finite-dimensional $KG$-module. Consider the endomorphisms of $V$, i.e. linear mappings $\phi : V \rightarrow V$ such that $g\phi(v) = \phi(gv)$ for all $g \in G, v \in V$.

Now, if the characteristic $\operatorname{char} K$ is coprime to $|G|$ (or $0$), then by Maschke's theorem, we can decompose $V$ into a direct sum of irreducible $KG$-Modules, and easily show the following property: if $V$ isn't irreducible (i.e. it is a direct sum of at least 2 summands), it has an endomorphism that is not simply a scalar multiple of $\operatorname{id}_V$: we can permute the summands, which is clearly an endomorphism (even an automorphism!) of $V$. Equivalently, if the only endomorphisms of $V$ are scalar multiples of $\operatorname{id}_V$, then $V$ is irreducible.

My question is now, whether this property holds in the case that $\operatorname{char} K$ and $|G|$ share some divisor. Since Maschke can fail in this case, my intuition would be that this shouldn't hold, but I cannot seem to construct a counterexample. For an "easy" example, I thought about using $V = \mathbb{F}_2^2$ over $K = \mathbb{F}_2$. To ensure that the only endomorphisms of $V$ are scalar multiples of $\operatorname{id}$, $G$ should at least contains elements that act on $V$ like the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, since the only matrices that commute with both of these are the identity and the zero-matrix. However, this also has the consequence that $V$ has no non-zero $KG$-subspaces.

If the property does hold in this case as well, how would I go about proving this?